# Como hacer paginacion PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Buenas tengo un codigo que recojo empleos de un custom post en wordpress, los voy mostrando en un **foreach**. Me gustaria saber alguna forma para hacer paginacion de 6 elementos por pagina.

```
 <?php
/* Template Name: Lista Jobs */

/**
 * Blog list template
 *
 * @package vogue
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

//Funciones
function check_in_range($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin, $fecha){

 $fecha_inicio = strtotime($fecha_inicio);
 $fecha_fin = strtotime($fecha_fin);
 $fecha = strtotime($fecha);

 if(($fecha >= $fecha_inicio) && ($fecha <= $fecha_fin)) {

     return true;

 } else {

     return false;

  }
}


// File Security Check
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

$config = Presscore_Config::get_instance();
$config->set( 'template', 'page' );

//Libreria para poder usar wordpress.
include('../../../wp-load.php');

//Argumentos para hacer la Query.
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'ofertasempleo',
'post_status '=> 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

//Obtenemos las clinicas del sistema.
$jobsAUX = new WP_Query($args);

//var_dump($jobsAUX);
//Si tenemos clinicas disponibles.
if ( $jobsAUX->have_posts() ) {
//Creamos pila de trabajos.
$jobs = array();

//Entramos en bucle para obtener los jobsAUX.
while ( $jobsAUX->have_posts() ) : $jobsAUX->the_post();
     $location = array(
            "titulo" => get_the_title(),
            "activo" => get_field("activo"),
            "imagen" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
            "url" => get_the_permalink(),
            "inicio" => get_field("fecha_inicio"),
            "fin" => get_field("fecha_fin")
        );
    //Almacenamos las posiciones.
    array_push($jobs, $location);
endwhile;

//Reseteamos el postdata.
wp_reset_postdata();
} 

get_header();

if ( presscore_is_content_visible() ): ?>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content" class="content content-empleo" role="main">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // main loop

                do_action( 'presscore_before_loop' );
                the_content();
                //Cotenido // SACAR STYLE DE AQUI
                ?>
                <div class="jobs-container">

                    <?php

                    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
                        $titulo = $job['titulo'];
                        $img = $job['imagen'];
                        $url = $job['url'];

                        $fechaInicio = $job['inicio'];
                        $fechaFin = $job['fin'];
                        $fechaActual = date('Y-m-d');
                        $caducado  = $job['activo'];

                        if($fechaInicio != null && $fechaFin != null){
                            $activo = check_in_range($fechaInicio,$fechaFin,$fechaActual);
                        }else{
                            $activo = $caducado;
                        }
                        ?>

                        <div class="cajaEmpleo">
                            <a class="empleoUrl" href="<?php echo $url;?>">
                                <div class="contenidoEmpleo">
                                    <div class="blackground">
                                        <img class="imgEmpleo" src="<?php echo $img;?>" alt="GMEDIA"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tituloEmpleo" >
                                        <h3><?php echo $titulo; ?></h3>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php if($activo){?>
                                        <div class="estadoEmpleo" style="background: #00a000;">Activa</div>
                                        <?php }else{ ?>
                                        <div class="estadoEmpleo" style="background: #be3631;">Caducada</div>
                                    <?php }?>

                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    }

                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Fin Contenido
                do_action( 'presscore_after_loop' );

            endwhile; endif; // main loop
            ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->

        <?php do_action('presscore_after_content');

endif; // if content visible

get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: La lógica sería recoger una variable **GET['numeroDePagina']**.

Limitar la consulta a un **máximo de 6 resultados.**

Según el número de página recibido, mostrar los resultados correspondientes. Por ejemplo: del 1 al maximoDeElementos en la página 1; del 7 + maximoDeElementos en la página 2.

En los links de la paginación deberás indicar el número de página que estás enviando por GET (o POST, según prefieras).

---
**Con una pequeña búsqueda en Google podrás ver cantidad de ejemplos con código.**

Comment: @JordiHuertas Nunca he tocado php son mis inicios he ido mirando varias webs con codigos de paginación pero no me queda claro, en función al código que tengo.

Comment: Entonces deberías primero aprender cómo funciona una paginación y, con los ejemplos de internet, crear tú una de prueba. Cuando lo entiendas deberás poder adaptarlo a lo que necesitas. Te paso un link bastante bien explicado: http://facturacionweb.site/blog/paginacion-simple-usando-php-mysqli/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mira el enlace que te he puesto en los comentarios**. De todas formas te planteo a continuación una lógica de paginación.

Te lo paso así porque tu pregunta es "No sé hacer una paginación en PHP" y no "He probado esto y aquello y sigue sin funcionar". Por tanto si necesitas saber cómo paginar deberías buscar y probar uno de los tantos tutoriales de Internet.(**https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**).

```
#Numero de elementos por pagina
$elementosPorPagina = 6;

#Checkea si se recibe numero de pagina y la asigna a variable. Si no se recibe la pagina sera la 1
if (!$_GET['numeroDePagina']){
    $numeroDePagina = 1;
}

$offset = $elementosPorPagina * $numeroDePagina + 1; #La Secuencia del offset de MySQL sería 1, 7, 13, 19...

#Consulta a BaseDeDatos 
SELECT [...]
WHERE [...]
LIMIT $elementosPorPagina OFFSET $offset;

#Bucle mostrando los resultados deseados en HTML

#Elementos de paginación, por ejemplo el de la página 1 sería:
if ($numeroDePagina > 1){
    [Elemento PaginaAnterior] = $numeroDePagina - 1;
}
else{
    [Elemento PaginaAnterior -> Disabled];
}
```

Comment: Es necesario hacer la paginación consultando la BBDD? Hay paginaciones de arreglos o no es posible? Perdona mi ignorancia en este tema, nunca habia tenido que hacer paginación, de esta forma.

Comment: Si es una paginación con PHP has de consultar cada vez. Con el LIMIT seleccionas qué resulados quieres (te he puesto un link a la documentación del limit en el código). --- En caso de que quieras hacerlo más dinámico con una consulta, la paginación se haría con Javascript. Te paso un link de SO resuelto con un ejemplo en vivo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034724/simple-jquery-pagination -> Solución ejemplo en vivo de @georg (https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) -> http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/184/

Comment: Una disculpa es que no puedo comentar, como puede indicar los $elementosPorPagina = 6; debes de poner el número, hacer que lo jale de un Select?